# How to implement Here Maps routing

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, here-api

I'm having trouble getting Here Maps' routing system working on web, for now by following the [official documentation](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/enterprise-maps/topics/routing.html).

The part that isn't clear is that I don't know how to call the `routingCallback()` function, or actually where to call it, and what are it's parameters.

The documentation states the following:

"*A route can be added to the map only after it has been calculated. For this reason, the routing manager must be given an observer to be called when the route is ready. The observer watches the Manager's property "state"*"

What exactly is this "observer" object? When should I call the `routingCallback()` function?

I am using the exact same code that can be found in the documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see the confusion, they don't show where/how to attach the observer.

Note however that you don't call the routingCallback yourself, the routing manager 
calls that function automatically once the async call is done
e.g.

```
var routingManager = new nokia.maps.advrouting.Manager();
routingManager.addObserver("state", routingCallback, routingManager);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is it. I have no idea why they couldn't include this row of code in the documentation, it would have made my life simpler..

Comment: Seems to be a common thing in their documentation ;)